# IF ELSE condition not working in UPDATE query

Tags: php

I want to update two columns based on one column value using if else condition.
If col1 is empty update col2 by adding random number.
else update col1 by adding random number.

I am trying this way but getting syntax error.

```
$query = "UPDATE table SET IF(col1='', col2=col2+FLOOR($min+(RAND()*($max-$min+1))), col1=col1+FLOOR($min+(RAND()*($max-$min+1)))) WHERE id >= $id";
```

Please see and suggest any possible way to do it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding of `IF()` in MySQL is a bit off: It is a control flow function, not a construct.

This means, that it is not ment e.g. to control **which column** to update, but **which value** to write into it.

So you need to regroup in a way, that makes the column(s) for `SET` invariant, while making the values variable. We achieve this by just reassigning the old value, if the condition for this column is not met.

```
UPDATE table SET 
  col2=IF(col1='', col2+FLOOR($min+(RAND()*($max-$min+1))), col2),
  col1=IF(col1='', col1, col1+FLOOR($min+(RAND()*($max-$min+1)))) 
WHERE id >= $id
```

**EDIT**

As from the comment: If you want to select on col1 being **etiher** the empty string **or** null, you have to select for it:

```
UPDATE table SET 
  col2=IF(col1='' OR col1 IS NULL, col2+FLOOR($min+(RAND()*($max-$min+1))), col2),
  col1=IF(col1='' OR col1 IS NULL, col1, col1+FLOOR($min+(RAND()*($max-$min+1)))) 
WHERE id >= $id
```

**EDIT 2**

If also col2 can be not only the empty string, but also null, you need to test for it again:

```
UPDATE table SET 
  col2=IF(col1='' OR col1 IS NULL, IFNULL(col2,0)+FLOOR($min+(RAND()*($max-$min+1))), col2),
  col1=IF(col1='' OR col1 IS NULL, col1, col1+FLOOR($min+(RAND()*($max-$min+1)))) 
WHERE id >= $id
```

Comment: Query is running , but the thing is that it not working some time it is updating and some time it doesn't even if col1 is null.

Comment: There is a major difference between an empty string and null - one is selected via `col1=''` and the other via `col1 IS NULL` !

Comment: Still not working on col2 null value, working only when col2 has a value not working on col1 has a value or is null.

Comment: There is no test on col2 being null - and there was none in you OQ. If col2 can be null, you need to test for it ... see edit

Answer (score -1):

```
//hi i just try this logic on my "mysql" may be it work on your system....
//plz take a llok to the logic i try


//i don't know about the case condition but i try to help and check that is it working on your function..


//here i select the whole table row with true condition 
//here i have single row which set true condition
$q = "select * from table where id>=".$id;
$r = mysql_query($q);


//i take one row at a time with ture contition and update values by checking column is empty or not 
//this llop run till the values are there  with true condition in select query
while($ro = mysql_fetch_array($r)){

//for every row in loop i check the condition that col1 is empty, if it is then i update col 2
if($ro['col1']==""){
$q_update = "update table set col2=".$rand." where id>=".$ro['id'];
$r_update = mysql_query($q_update);
}
//for every row in loop i check the condition that col1 is empty, if it is not then i update col1
else{
$q_update = "update table set col1=".$rand." where id>=".$ro['id'];
$r_update = mysql_query($q_update);
}


}//while loop ends here
```

Comment: This way ill be executing same query many times as long as while loop runs instead of just running it one time.

Comment: yes, i use while loop here because you use this "WHERE id >= $id" 
it means you have more then one row (which have id grater then $id).
so i put loop and getting data of rows one by one and updating them one by one in loop...

Comment: This way it will work but its not the best approach when you have many rows, I am looking for single query approach if you can help.

Comment: ok thanks for tell me this is working on your system and i am also finding the query for you....but this is also i good way to update data...!!!

Comment: I have not tested your approach exactly as you posted , I tried this way on my own before it took fairly long time to update, then i used single query approach which took only seconds but problem arises when i had to update based on another column value.